# Export all layers of GPKG to Shapefile with QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis, export, geopackage

Is there a way to export all layers of a GPKG (Geopackage) database to shapefiles in ONE STEP? Or just a selection? It's a lot of work to export all layers one by one.

Comment: Did you try batch processing of the Convert format tool in Processing - GDAL?.

Answer (score 8):

Not a QGIS solution, but very quick using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) with the commandline:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_folder input.gpkg
```

Answer (score 3):

Download the QPackage Plugin.

When you run this you can select which layers you want saved and it will export them all as shapefiles.

The opposite of this is the Package Layers processing tool which saves everything off as a geopackage.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like a good plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it with pythoncode you can use that script from the python console

```
from osgeo import ogr
source = ogr.Open('d:/tonne/workshop1.gpkg',update=False)
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
for i in source:
    LayerName = i.GetName() 
    inlyr = source.GetLayer( LayerName )
    outds = drv.CreateDataSource( 'd:/tonne/' + LayerName + '.shp')
    outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(inlyr,LayerName)
del inlyr,outlyr,outds
```